# Align tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Is there a way to align tables in LaTeX?

I was writing a document with several tables in the same page, and often the edges don't match.

I would like to have tables aligned in both left and right edge.

```
\paragraph{Articoli}
\begin{large}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
\hline
\textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} 
\\    \hline
& & & 1500 occorrenze \\ \hline
Codice & Char(7) & 7 & 10,7 kB \\ \hline
Nome  &  Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB  \\ \hline
Marca & Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB \\ \hline
Prezzo & Money & 8 & 12,2 kB \\ \hline
Disponibile & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
Soglia & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
Reparto & Char (4) & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
Totale &  & &   321 kB      \\ \hline
Dati + Block Header & & & 322 kB \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\paragraph{Reparti}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo}        
     \\ \hline
    & & & 120 occorrenze \\ \hline
    Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,5 kB  \\ \hline
    Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 12.1 kB \\ \hline
    Sezione & Char(4) & 4 & 0.5 kB \\ \hline
    Totale &  & &  12.2 kB        \\ \hline
    Dati + Block Header & & & 12.3 kB \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
  \paragraph{Pagamenti}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\ \hline
    & & & 10 occorrenze  \\ \hline
    Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,1 kB \\ \hline
    Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 1 kB  \\ \hline
            Totale &  & &  1.1 kB       \\ \hline
            Dati + Block Header & & & 1.2 kB  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Duplicate posted: [How to align tables in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220020/5764)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Tex, and was cross-posted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220020/how-to-align-tables-in-latex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this alignment:

1. Use a single `tabular` that would contain everything. This ensures the columns all use the same width:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{ l | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
     \cline{2-5}
     & \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \cline{2-5}
     & & & & 1500 occorrenze \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Codice & Char(7) & 7 & 10,7 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Nome  &  Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB  \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Marca & Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     \textbf{Articoli} & Prezzo & Money & 8 & 12,2 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Disponibile & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Soglia & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Reparto & Char (4) & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Totale &  & &   321 kB      \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Dati + Block Header & & & 322 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{}\\[\bigskipamount]
     \cline{2-5}
     & \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \cline{2-5}
     & & & & 120 occorrenze \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,5 kB  \\ \cline{2-5}
     \textbf{Reparti} & Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 12.1 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Sezione & Char(4) & 4 & 0.5 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Totale &  & &  12.2 kB        \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Dati + Block Header & & & 12.3 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     \multicolumn{1}{l}{}\\[\bigskipamount]
     \cline{2-5}
     & \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \cline{2-5}
     & & & & 10 occorrenze  \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,1 kB \\ \cline{2-5}
     \raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\textbf{Pagamenti}} &
       Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 1 kB  \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Totale &  & &  1.1 kB       \\ \cline{2-5}
     & Dati + Block Header & & & 1.2 kB  \\ \cline{2-5}
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Drawbacks here are the tables don't break across the page boundary (unless you use something like [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable)).
2. Use boxes/overlapping/phantoms to adjust the appropriate entries so they align:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   \leavevmode\rlap{\textbf{Articoli}}%
   \phantom{\textbf{Pagamenti}}
   \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
     \hline
     \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \hline
     & & & 1500 occorrenze \\ \hline
     Codice & Char(7) & 7 & 10,7 kB \\ \hline
     Nome  &  Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB  \\ \hline
     Marca & Varchar (100) & 100 & 150 kB \\ \hline
     Prezzo & Money & 8 & 12,2 kB \\ \hline
     Disponibile & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
     Soglia & Integer & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
     Reparto & Char (4) & 4 & 6.2 kB \\ \hline
     Totale &  & &   321 kB      \\ \hline
     Dati + Block Header & & & 322 kB \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

   \bigskip

   \leavevmode\rlap{\textbf{Reparti}}%
   \phantom{\textbf{Pagamenti}}
   \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
     \hline
     \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \hline
     & & & 120 occorrenze \\ \hline
     Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,5 kB  \\ \hline
     Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 12.1 kB \\ \hline
     Sezione & Char(4) & 4 & 0.5 kB \\ \hline
     Totale &  & &  12.2 kB        \\ \hline
     Dati + Block Header & & & 12.3 kB \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

   \bigskip

   \textbf{Pagamenti}
   \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{3cm} |}
     \hline
     \textbf{Attributo} & \textbf{Tipo} & \textbf{Byte} & \textbf{Complessivo} \\
     \hline
     & & & 10 occorrenze  \\ \hline
     Codice & Char(4) & 4 & 0,1 kB \\ \hline
     Nome  &  Varchar (100) &  100 & 1 kB  \\ \hline
     Totale &  & &  1.1 kB       \\ \hline
     Dati + Block Header & & & 1.2 kB  \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Note the use of `%` at the end of the overlapping line; this is to avoid a spurious space. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Here is another presentation using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), foregoing the excessive use of horizontal rules and no vertical rules at all:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,etoolbox}
\newcommand{\tipochar}[1]{Char~(#1)}
\newcommand{\tipovarchar}[1]{Varchar~(#1)}
\newcommand{\tipomoney}{Money}
\newcommand{\tipointeger}{Integer}

\sisetup{%
  round-integer-to-decimal, 
  round-precision = 1,
  round-mode = places
}%
\robustify\bfseries
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ 
    >{\hspace*{1em}\itshape}l
    l
    S[table-format = 3.1]
    S[table-format = 3.2]}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Attributo} & 
    \bfseries Tipo & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Byte} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Complessivo [kB]} \\
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Articoli} &            &     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\num{1500} occorrenze} \\
    Codice              & \tipochar{7}      &   7 &  10.7 \\
    Nome                & \tipovarchar{100} & 100 & 150   \\
    Marca               & \tipovarchar{100} & 100 & 150   \\
    Prezzo              & \tipomoney        &   8 &  12.2 \\
    Disponibile         & \tipointeger      &   4 &   6.2 \\
    Soglia              & \tipointeger      &   4 &   6.2 \\
    Reparto             & \tipochar{4}      &   4 &   6.2 \\
    Totale              &                   &     & 321   \\
    Dati + Block Header &                   &     & 322   \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Reparti} &             &     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\num{120} occorrenze} \\ 
    Codice              & \tipochar{4}      &   4 &   0.5 \\
    Nome                & \tipovarchar{100} & 100 &  12.1 \\
    Sezione             & \tipochar{4}      &   4 &   0.5 \\
    Totale              &                   &     &  12.2 \\
    Dati + Block Header &                   &     &  12.3 \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pagamenti} &           &     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\num{10} occorrenze} \\
    Codice              & \tipochar{4}      &   4 &   0.1 \\
    Nome                & \tipovarchar{100} & 100 &   1   \\
    Totale              &                   &     &   1.1 \\
    Dati + Block Header &                   &     &   1.2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```